# How to add post title to custom php?

Tags: plugins, templates

I need to create a template to replace the default page of Events Made Easy. I created a php file for this template and copied the page.php code to the new php file.

```
    <?php

// Exit if accessed directly.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

get_header();
nectar_page_header( $post->ID );
$nectar_fp_options = nectar_get_full_page_options();

?>

<div class="container-wrap">
    <div class="<?php if ( $nectar_fp_options['page_full_screen_rows'] !== 'on' ) { echo 'container'; } ?> main-content">
        <div class="row">

            <?php

            nectar_hook_before_content(); 

            if ( have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts() ) :

                    the_post();
                    the_content();

                endwhile;
            endif;

            nectar_hook_after_content();

            ?>

        </div><!--/row-->
    </div><!--/container-->
</div><!--/container-wrap-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now I need to get the title in there. I'm using the following code, but all I get is the title of the page itself and not of the post.

```
     <header class="entry-header">
             <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  </header>
```

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you placing the `<?php the_title():?>` inside the loop? After the `while ( have_posts() ) :`

Comment: Thanks, Dan. Actually I didn't have anything there. I placed it where you recommenced and the page crashed, so I changed the_title to the_post and that solved the issue. Thanks so much.